# How can I select the row(s) which contains the maximum value in a column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table as follows:

```
|name|extra|value|
|a   |m    |1    |
|b   |n    |2    |
|c   |o    |3    |
|d   |p    |4    |
```

I want to select `(d, p)` from it.

If I add a row so my table is now:

```
|name|extra|value|
|a   |m    |1    |
|b   |n    |2    |
|c   |o    |3    |
|d   |p    |4    |
|e   |q    |4    |
```

Then I want to get two rows back from my table, `(d,p)` and `(e, q)`.
How can I achieve this in Postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the max of values as an argument in the where clause:

```
select name, extra
from table
where value = (select max (value) from table)
```

Comment: Perfect thanks! I didn't realize that the max had to be a subquery.